About the action of standard generators on weight spaces of a semisimple Lie algebra
I am currently studying weight decompositions for representations of semisimple Lie Algebras, and a question arose, which I have not found a way to answer yet.
Let L be a finite dimensional semisimple complex Lie Algebra and $\rho \colon L \to gl(V)$ a representation of L with a finite dimensional $V$. Further let H be a Cartan Subalgebra of L. Then V has a decomposition consisting of eigenspaces of $\rho(H)$ of the form:
$$V = \bigoplus V_\lambda$$
where $V_\lambda$ is the weight space for elements of $\rho(H)$, and $\lambda \in H^*$. Further let $\Phi$ be the set of roots of $L$ w.r. to $H$ with base $\Delta$, and denote $L_\alpha$ for $\alpha \in \Phi$ be the rootspace of $\alpha$ according to the usual root decomposition. Last, let $\{x_i, y_i, h_i\}$ be a set of standard generators according to the basis $\Delta$.
Now lets say that we know that both $\lambda, \lambda+\alpha$ is a weight for this decomposition, where the simple root $\alpha$ belongs to index $i$ in the generator set.  I can see that
$$x_i(V_\lambda) \subseteq V_{\lambda + \alpha}$$
I now want to prove that the map:
$$x_i \colon V_\lambda \to V_{\lambda + \alpha}$$
is nonzero.
I managed to prove that this is equivalent to the fact, that any highest weight vector indeed belongs to a highest weight, but unfortunately I also do not know that the latter fact is true. I tried approaches using the decomposition into irreducible $sl(\alpha)$-submodules of:
$$\bigoplus V_{\lambda + n \alpha}$$
but this did not lead me anywhere. I would be thankful for help.
EDIT:
Does this also hold when $\alpha$ is a normal (if needed positive), and not necessarily a simple root? So if $\lambda, \lambda + \alpha$ both are weights, is the map $x\colon V_\lambda \to V_{\lambda + \alpha}$ nonzero?
EDIT:
Because nobody answered this yet, is this even correct? When I try to prove it, I always encounter Situations where it seems possible for two weight spaces in  $$\bigoplus V_{\lambda + n \alpha}$$ to be "disconnected" by $x_i$.

You must impose the condition that $V$ is irreducible. Otherwise, There is a counter example ---  $sl_2$ Verma modules with dominant integral weights.

Can you elaborate that counter example as an answer?

Are you interested in the general case, or the case dim$(V)< \infty$?

The case of finite dimension, sorry for not clarifiying that earlier, in my book, everything is always of finite dimension that is why I forgot to mention it.

If $V$ is finite dimensional and $L$ is semi-simple, then any representation is a direct sum of irreducible representations. On each irreducible representation, there is an invariant metric such that $x_i$ and $y_i$ are adjoint to each other and $h_i$ are self-adjoint. Using these properties, you may be able to prove the wanted property.

Well, I'll just indicate the case when $L=sl_{2}$. Suppose $x:V_{\lambda} \to V_{\lambda+\alpha}$ is zero. Then by taking adjoints, $y:V_{\lambda+\alpha} \to V_{\lambda}$ is also zero. This means that $V$ splits into two submodules, $\bigoplus_{\mu\leq \lambda} V_{\mu}$ and $\bigoplus_{\mu\geq \lambda+\alpha} V_{\mu}$, which are not connected by ${x,y,h}$-actions. This contradict with the irreducibility of $V$.

@A.Kato I think I figured out the irreducible $sl_2$ case, but only because in that case all weight spaces have dimension $1$. Can you now please elaborate on the more general problem? I do not see however how you saw that $y$ would also be zero in that case.

I'm not an expert in representation theory, so please do not rely so much on me.... Please consult standard reference such as Chapter VI of Humphreys "Introduction to Lie algebras and Representation Theory".

This follows from straightforward observations about (finite dimensional) $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ representations. All irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ representations are just a chain of weight spaces $V = V_{-\lambda} \oplus V_{-\lambda +2} \oplus \cdots \oplus V_{\lambda}$. In particular their eigenvalues are symmetric around $0$. But you know the eigenvalues in your chain (they are the weights $\lambda + k \alpha$ applied to our coroot $H_\alpha \in \mathfrak{sl}(\alpha)$). So there is no space for disconnected "weight strings" as all irreducible pieces are centred around the same place. If $\lambda$ and $\lambda + \alpha$ are both weights for the representation there is at least one irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}(\alpha)$ representation intersecting non-trivially with $V_\lambda$ and $V_{\lambda + \alpha}$. Indeed intersecting with one of them implies intersecting with the other. Whichever is further from being the "$0$-eigenspace" (more directly the one whose inner product with $\alpha$ is furthest from $0$). Thus $x_\alpha:V_\lambda \to V_{\lambda+\alpha}$ is non-zero.
Note I am not assuming $\alpha$ is a simple root or anything like that. I'm not even sure that we need to assume our original representation is irreducible but I might be overlooking something there.

I do not understand this proof, I agree with everything up to the phrase:
"If $\lambda$  and $\lambda + \alpha$ are both weights ..." - Can you elaborate on that?

@Goldstern420 I've edited to make myself a little clearer.

Why should there be such a irreducible $sl(\alpha)$ representations that intersects non trivially? Where do you take that from?

@Goldstern420 From the previous part of my answer. For all representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, any non-zero eigenspace is "connected" to the eigenspace at $0$ (or the two eigenspaces around $0$). Whichever of your weight spaces is "further out" implies that the other weight space is also on all the same irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-representations.

@Goldstern420 Indeed I'm underselling the result. Let's assume $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ are both positive or both negative. Then any irreducible representations intersecting nontrivially with $V_{\lambda+\alpha}$ must also intersect nontrivially with $V_{\lambda}$ since it is a step closer to $0$. If $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ have different signs then it is the other way around.

I think I get where you are coming from now, however one needs irreducibility for the $sl(\alpha)$ module for this to work. Why do we have that?

Ah, one does not need that, by complete reducibility we can decompose, than we get the chains you talk about. We only care about the one chain which contains something out of $V_\lambda$, and this chain should be the "desired" one?

Okay, I think I get the intersection part now. However, why is the result true for $sl(\alpha)$? Can we use the argument that if it would be zero for this $v \in V_\lambda$, then this $v$ would be a highest weight vector. However, we now that this one is unique for $sl(\alpha)$ reps. and because we know that there is another one, this would be a contradiction?

@Goldstern420 It's not that there is only one such chain. We just need only one chain to exist to show it is non-zero. I'm not sure what your last comment is aiming to show. There isn't a unique highest weight here as the general representation is not irreducible when restricted to $\mathfrak{sl}(\alpha)$. Why would we need it though? We're already using higher level facts about $\mathfrak{sl}(\alpha)$ reps.

I will give a detailed description as an answer to add to your existing one, please let me know if you agree @Callum. If so, then I can accept your answer.

@Goldstern420 Yes your answer is fine. I still think the contradiction part isn't really necessary as we are already using the much stronger fact that irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-representations are generated by $v, x(v), x^2(v),\dots$ to get these eigenspaces.

Edit: I overlooked that OP wants $V$ to be finite dimensional.
So the following ''counter-example'' is not relevant to the question. I could delete my answer, but the comments/discussion from other people might be useful, so I decided to leave it as is.
....
This is an expanded version of my comment.
You want to prove that:
the map: $x_{i}:V_{\lambda}\to V_{\lambda+\alpha}$ is nonzero.
But the claim above is not true in general. There is a counter-example: $sl_{2}$ Verma modules $M_{\lambda}$ with dominant integral weights.
Let $E$, $F$, $H$ be the standard generators of $sl_2$ such that
$$
  [E,F]=H,~~ [H,E]=2E,~~ [H,F]=-2F.
$$
The Verma module $M_{\lambda}$ is spanned by the vectors of the form
$F^{k} v_{\lambda}$, ($k=0,1,2,\dots$) where $v_{\lambda}$ be the highest weight vector with
$Hv_{\lambda}=\lambda v_{\lambda}$. Thus each weight space is one dimensional, and $HF^{k}v_{\lambda}=(\lambda-2k)F^{k}v_{\lambda}$.
Using the commutation relation, one can check that
$$ EF^n v_{\lambda}=
(\lambda+(\lambda-2)+\cdots+(\lambda-2(k-1)))F^{n-1} v_{\lambda} 
= n(\lambda-1+n) F^{n-1}v_{\lambda}
$$
Therefore, although the map $F:\mathbb{C}F^{n}v_{\lambda}\to \mathbb{C}F^{n+1}v_{\lambda}$ never vanishes, the map $E: \mathbb{C}F^{n}v_{\lambda}\to \mathbb{C}F^{n-1}v_{\lambda}$ is zero if $\lambda-1+n=0$. In this case, we have another highest weight vector in $M_{\lambda}$, indicating the reducibility of $M_{\lambda}$.

I don't think this works: the OP assumes both $\lambda$ and $\lambda+\alpha$ are weights of the representation, and the latter is not true in your example. In fact, the case $\lambda - 1 + n =0$ is precisely the canonical way of constructing $\mathfrak{sl}2$-irreps (so $M\lambda$ is not reducible here). If $\lambda+\alpha$ is not a weight, then there should be a vector with weight $\lambda$ on which $E$ annihilates.

Are you assuming $\lambda$ is always the highest weight? But when OP refers to both $\lambda$ and $\lambda+\alpha$, the weight $\lambda$ is never the highest one -- just a weight in $V$.

See for example the section 1 of this.

OK, I have now understood what you were trying to do, and I agree that this works: could you clarify your post a bit, fixing the [H,F] commutator and stating that you postulate that $F^n_\lambda \neq 0$ for all $n$?

Thanks for pointing out my typo. Well, the fact that $F^n v_{\lambda}\neq 0$ for all $n\geq 0$ just follows from the definition of the Verma module.

I know that, but since you are trying to explain this to someone else who is likely unfamiliar with that concept, it is just good teaching to make that explicit. To add to that, making it clear that a generic Verma module is infinite-dimensional would be prudent as well.

But does that not mean that this module if of infinite dimension?

@Goldstern420 Yes, it does (at least in the case of interest here): suppose $\lambda - 1 + n = 0$, then there are 2 options here: either $F^n v_\lambda = 0$, which leads to the standard $\mathfrak{sl}2$ irrep. This is finite-dimensional, but does not provide a counter-example of your claim. If instead $F^n v\lambda$ is a non-trivial vector that is annihilated by $E$ the resulting module is infinite-dimensional, forming an example of a weight-space on which $E$ acts as zero.

But I am looking for finite dimensional cases, sorry for not beeing more explicit about that.

You are right. I overlooked that the assumption that $V$ is finite dimensional. Sorry for that.

@A.Kato you didn't overlook it, it wasn't there in the original question

This is supposed to be an extension of @Callum 's answer, as it is good, but I think for further readers a full proof would be nice.
Let us view $\bar{V}:= \bigoplus V_{\lambda + n \alpha}$ as a $sl(\alpha)$ rep. We know that $\bar{V}$ is completely reducible. Let
$$\bar{V}=V_1, \oplus \dots, \oplus V_k$$
be the decomposition into irreducible submodules.
Now there are two cases we want to handle individually: $\lambda(z_\alpha) < 0$ and $\lambda(z_\alpha) >0$ ($z_\alpha \in H$ is supposed to be the coroot of $\alpha$ ($\alpha(z_\alpha = 2$))):

First let $\lambda(z_\alpha) < 0$.
Some $V_i$ must contain something out of $V_{\lambda}$. Let us fix this $V_i$ and call it $W$ from now on, let $v$ be the element it contains.
We know now that $W$ is a irreducible $sl(\alpha)$ submodule. We can decompose:
$$W = W_{-m} \oplus W_{-m + 2} \oplus \dots \oplus W_m$$
where $W_j$ denote the eigenspaces of $z_\alpha$ on $W$ with eigenvalue $j$.
We know that $v \in W$, so it must live in one of those spaces, denote that by $W_i$. We now know that:
$$ i = \lambda(z_\alpha) < 0$$
Therefore in the decomposition of $W$ the space $W_{i+2}$ is non trivial, because it is higher in the chain. But its elements have the eigenvalue $\lambda(z_\alpha) + 2$, so they lie in $V_{\lambda + \alpha}$. Now we claim that $x_\alpha \cdot v \neq 0$. Indeed if this was zero, $v$ would be a vector of highest weight, but this is unique for $sl(\alpha)$ reps. and we know that there is a higher weight ($i+2$), so there is surely another highest weight vector. Therefore  $x_\alpha \cdot v \neq 0$

Now let $\lambda(z_\alpha) \geq 0$.
Some $V_i$ must contain something out of $V_{\lambda + \alpha}$. Let us fix this $V_i$ and call it $W$ from now on, let $v$ be the element it contains. Again as above we can decompose:
$$W = W_{-m} \oplus W_{-m + 2} \oplus \dots \oplus W_m$$
With a similiar trick as above, we know that the space $W_{i-2}$ is non trivial, because it is one step lower in the chain. But the elements of $W_{i-2}$ all live in $V_\lambda$. Now let $0 \neq w \in W_{i-2}$. We claim that $x_\alpha \cdot w \neq 0$. Again, the highest weight vector is unique, $i$ is a higher weight so we conlude that $x_\alpha \cdot w \neq 0$.

To summarize, we did not assume anything special here. $\alpha$ is just a root, not necessarily a simple root. Also $V$ is not needed to be irreducible.
